# graph neural networks for molecular embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, ai, graph-neural-network

I want to extract the embeddings from various graph neural network designed for small molecules. I want to know does the model need to be trained to do the same. Or should be extract the layer in forward pass. I'm new to this area of GNNs hence asking. Please shed light.